# Get multiple Post_meta and display lowest value

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm setting up a website with multiple prices all stored in a custom field. I want to grab all those custom fields and display only the lowest number.

Php is my weakness and I haven't tried anything yet other then a simple `get_post_meta`

I can call all the post_meta via these codes

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save1', true); ?> - returns £499.99
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save2', true); ?> - returns £499.99
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save3', true); ?> - returns £489.99
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save4', true); ?> - returns £424.99
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save5', true); ?> - returns £529.99
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save6', true); ?>`- returns £589.99
```

I'm hoping to do something along the lines of displaying the lowest number from each of the `price_save#` custom fields

In the interest of learning a bit of PHP I am guessing I will need some sort of array to collect all the numbers then do something to remove all but the lowest.

I have attempted this but with no luck so far

```
<?php 

$prices = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save1', 'price_save2', 'price_save3'); // get all prices
rsort($prices); // sort in descending order

$min_price = $prices[0]; // lowest
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show your returned results from each of the get_post_meta() calls?

Comment: I've added what they return which are just £##.## numbers.

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
$post_meta_1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save1', TRUE);
$post_meta_2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save2', TRUE);
$post_meta_3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save3', TRUE);
$post_meta_4 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save4', TRUE);
$post_meta_5 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save5', TRUE);
$post_meta_6 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save6', TRUE);
$post_meta_7 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_save7', TRUE);
$price1=str_replace("£","",$post_meta_1);
$price2=str_replace("£","",$post_meta_2);
$price3=str_replace("£","",$post_meta_3);
$price4=str_replace("£","",$post_meta_4);
$price5=str_replace("£","",$post_meta_5);
$price6=str_replace("£","",$post_meta_6);
$price7=str_replace("£","",$post_meta_7);

$numbers = array($price1, $price2, $price3, $price4, $price5, $price6, $price7);

$min = min($numbers);
$max = max($numbers);
```